# Coded UI test and Load test

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have been searching the internet but have not been able to find any real information on, is it possible to have coded UI test recorded in VS that can run with a load test in VS?

If it is could some point out the steps on how to connect the coded UI test to the Load test as I have not been able to find out how to do this.

I am trying to load test a UI which I want a certain route to be taken. I am using VS 2012 but can use VS 2010 if it is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read [Using Coded UI Tests in Load Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn250793.aspx). Then

- Create a Coded UI Test and make sure that it is working
- Create a load test and in the test mix step of the load test wizard, add the Coded UI test that you created and configure the rest of the load test as you need.

Note that the Coded UI tests drive the mouse and the keyboard so you will only be able to have a single virtual user running at a time per test agent. You will also need to make sure the test agents are configured to run in [interactive process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx) mode.